# case sensitive search is limiting results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am trying to modify my search so that if a user searches "wrangler" they will get the same results as searching "Wrangler". The database has the first letter capitalized so I guess I need to upcase my search if lowercase .. not sure how to accomplish this --- basically, I do not want the capitalization to come into play at all when searching.

my search form:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :heading %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :heading %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :neighborhood %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :neighborhood %>
  </div> -->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :external_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :external_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :timestamp %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :timestamp %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def home
end

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.order('timestamp DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    @posts = @posts.where(model: params["model"]) if params["model"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where(year: params["year"]) if params["year"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where(neighborhood: params["neighborhood"]) if params["neighborhood"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where("price > ?", params["min_price"]) if params["min_price"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where("price < ?", params["max_price"]) if params["max_price"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where(transmission: params["transmission"]) if params["transmission"].present?
    @posts = @posts.where(title_status: params["title_status"]) if params["title_status"].present?
  end

  # GET /posts/
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Sqlite3 local / pg live on heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example.

```
@posts = @posts.where( all, :conditions => ["lower(model) =?", params["model"].downcase]) if params["model"].present?
```

What happens here **lower(field_name)** makes the value of the field lower case

**params[:name].downcase** makes the value lower case

Comment: do  i add this as a new line?

Comment: Yeas you can do this in a new line. Make sure to change name yo the field you want to make insensitive

Comment: ok, getting an action controller error ...the field i want to make insensitive is "model" ..i tried this  ..  @post = @post.where( ["lower(name) = ?", params[:model].downcase] )

Comment: Look at the answer again I added :all, :conditions =>

Comment: ok ..so do i need to change anything? where do I insert "model" .? sorry I am a rails beginner...

Comment: getting: undefined local variable or method `all' for #<PostsController:0x63ac3b0>

Comment: Show me your where statement again

Comment: @posts = @posts.where(model: params["model"]) if params["model"].present?

Comment: @posts = @posts.where( all, :conditions =>    ["lower(model) =?", params["model"].downcase) if params["model"].present?

Comment: ok almost now just getting a syntax error....  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' ... =?", params["model"].downcase) if params["model"].present? ... ... ^

Comment: there must be a missing "]" or ")" somewhere?

Comment: rather... what should my 'def all' look like?

Answer (score 1):

@posts = @posts.where( all, :conditions =>    ["lower(model) =?", params["model"].downcase]) if params["model"].present?

Comment: The search submits but it isn't working correctly ..something with the def all I believe ...